# Are factors stored more efficiently in data.table than characters?

Tags: r, memory, data.table

I thought I had read somewhere (can't remember where) that factors were not actually more efficient than character vectors in data.table.  Is this true?  I was debating whether to continue using factors to store various vectors in data.table.  An approximate test with `object.size` seems to indicate otherwise.

```
chars <- data.table(a = sample(letters, 1e5, TRUE))           # chars (not really)
string <- data.table(a = sample(state.name, 1e5, TRUE))       # strings
fact <- data.table(a = factor(sample(letters, 1e5, TRUE)))    # factor
int <- data.table(a = sample(1:26, 1e5, TRUE))                # int

mbs <- function(...) {
    ns <- sapply(match.call(expand.dots=TRUE)[-1L], deparse)
    vals <- mget(ns, .GlobalEnv)
    cat('Sizes:\n',
        paste('\t', ns, ':', round(sapply(vals, object.size)/1024/1024, 3), 'MB\n'))
}

## Get approximate sizes?
mbs(chars, string, fact, int)
# Sizes:
#    chars : 0.765 MB
#    string : 0.766 MB
#    fact : 0.384 MB
#    int : 0.382 MB
```

Comment: Others reading this question may be interested in R's general behaviour; according to Hadley Wickham, "R has a global string pool. This means that each unique string is only stored in one place, and therefore character vectors take up less memory than you might expect." See http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You may be remembering data.table FAQ 2.17 which contains :

> stringsAsFactors is by default TRUE in data.frame but FALSE in data.table, for efficiency. Since a global string cache was added to R, characters items are a pointer to the single cached string and there is no longer a performance benefit of converting to factor.

(That part was added to the FAQ in v1.8.2 in July 2012.)

Using character rather than factor helps a lot in tasks like stacking (rbindlist). Since a `c()` of two character vectors is just the concatenation whereas a `c()` of two factor columns needs to traverse and union the two factor levels which is harder to code and takes longer to execute.

What you've noticed is a difference in RAM consumption on 64bit machines. Factors are stored as an `integer` vector lookup of the items in the levels. Type `integer` is 32bit, even on 64bit platforms. But pointers (what a `character` vector is) are 64bit on 64bit machines.  So a character column will use twice as much RAM than a factor column on 64bit machine. No difference on 32bit. However, usually this cost will be outweighed by the simpler and faster instructions possible on a character vector.  [Aside: since factors are `integer` they can't contain more than 2 billion unique strings. `character` columns don't have that limitation.]

It depends on what you're doing but operations have been optimized for `character` in data.table and so that's what we advise. Basically it saves a hop (to levels) and we can compare two character columns in different tables just by comparing the pointer values without hopping at all, even to the global cache.

It depends on the cardinality of the column, too. Say the column is 1 million rows and contains 1 million unique strings.  Storing it as a factor will need a 1 million character vector for the levels plus a 1 million integer vector pointing to the level's elements.  That's (4+8)*1e6 bytes. A character vector on the other hand won't need the levels and it's just 8*1e6 bytes. In both cases the global cache stores the 1 million unique strings in the same way so that happens anyway. In this case, the character column will use less RAM than if it were a factor. Careful to check that the memory tool used to calculate the RAM usage is calculating this appropriately.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-ints.html#The-CHARSXP-cache  then search for mkChar() in source.